# SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PKCS11_ERROR when trying to run curl command in rhel7

Tags: ssl, curl, rhel7, nss, p12

I am trying to run curl command from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 server with curl below:-
`*curl -0 -v --cert-type p12 --cert /mycert.p12:<password> --cacert /my_sec_cert.cer -X GET "https://<url>"*`
and ended up with the error :-
unable to load client cert: -8018 (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PKCS11_ERROR)

- NSS error -8018 (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PKCS11_ERROR)

When i am using pem certificate for same curl command with private key. Its working fine for me.

Can anyone suggest how to use p12 with Rhel7 here? Thanks